# How do I send files from my personal computer to a cluster?

Tags: scp, cluster

I know to send files onto my laptop from the cluster, I do something like:

scp username@remotecomputer:/path/to/file/you/want/to/copy where/to/put/file/on/laptop

But what about uploading a file from my laptop? I guess I need to know what username@remotecomputer for my laptop is???

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks. I update my question.

Comment: so SCP can be used both to download and upload files, so you just need to swap your arguments. to download to the laptop, from the laptop run `scp username@remotecomputer:/path/to/file/you/want/to/copy where/to/put/file/on/laptop` and to upload to the cluster, from the laptop, you just use  `scp /path/to/file/you/want/to/copy username@remotecomputer:/where/to/put/file/on/cluster` see here for more examples for SCP: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/scp-command-tutorial/

Comment: +1 That's so helpful! I appreciate it.

Comment: also, there are lots of guis out there for SFTP (an upgraded version of SCP, which like SCP uses SSH as its transport. has no relation to the FTP protocol). for most linux desktops, you can just use the file browser (nautilus, caja, etc) and enter a path like `sshfs://server/path/to/whatever`. on windows WinSCP is a good gui. I'm sure the mac people have some tooling as well.